# How can I display the current DNS servers from the command line under OS X?

Tags: command-line, dns

I want to display the DNS servers that are used by the current network setup on OS X, from the command line.

Comment: Same question: https://superuser.com/questions/258151/how-do-i-check-what-dns-server-im-using-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 126):

There are several ways - here are two:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

-or-

```
scutil --dns
```

Comment: Its extremely annoying that `networksetup -getdnsservers` doesn't work for DHCP-assigned DNS servers. I always forget about `scutil`. The 'sc' stands for System Configuration? It sure doesn't configure much of the system...

Comment: It's also good to note that `dig` or `nslookup` don't necessarily give a realistic picture of how the macOS applications resolve domain names from the local system, especially when multiple (domain-specific) DNSes have been configured, such as when using a VPN client for multiple concurrent connections. Instead of `nslookup` or `dig`, use `dscacheutil -q host -a name somehostname.com` to test DNS resolution. It takes into account all configured DNS servers as well as their priority order.

Comment: `cat /etc/resolv.conf` doesn't seem like a "reliable" solution anymore. This is the notice I get in macOS High Sierra when using it: (sorry for the formatting - comments don't support simple line breaks)

# macOS Notice
#
# This file is not consulted for DNS hostname resolution, address
# resolution, or the DNS query routing mechanism used by most
# processes on this system.
#
# To view the DNS configuration used by this system, use:
#   scutil --dns

Comment: I like `scutil --dns | grep nameserver` to _just_ get the DNS servers.

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` is no more used, but `scutil --dns` gives to-the-point info.

Answer (score 6):

The following shell command can be useful to list the current DNS entries:

```
grep nameserver <(scutil --dns)
```

To filter it out for the script, you can pipe the output into `awk '{print $3}'` or `grep -o "[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+"` command.

Comment: This is the same as `scutil --dns | grep nameserver` correct (just different syntax)?

Comment: @SamAndrew81 correct same

Comment: Technically this is [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), where the `<(...)` creates a FIFO that can (often) be used in place of a file name. In this case, `grep` can either read from stdin or a file, so either technique works, but they are not synonyms.

Comment: Also `scutil --dns | ` creates a pipe, so at least w.r.t the result is the same, and I find it more intuitive to use than `<(scutil --dns)` because the data flow is "from left to right".

Answer (score 0):

To get all into a comma separated line:

```
scutil --dns | sed -n '/nameserver/ { s/^.* : \(.*\)/\1/p; }' | sort -u | paste -s -d',' -
```

Comment: grep is much simpler why use the complex regexp?

Comment: Which complex regex? I would differ that dots and starts are a complex regex... in any case this returns the IPs separated by commas, grep cannot extract those values, it just select lines. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Any regex including \ is complex to me and I suspect most programmers. ANyway it is more complex in this case than grep. The OP only wants to display the IPs so why go more complex

Comment: ok. '\' is an escape sequence, not part of the regex, but part of `sed`. The title of my answer already states what this does, which is what I needed (and anyone doing anything with the IP afterwards within the same shell). I'm sorry you don't like that I shared.

Comment: that is my point to enter a regex you need to escape characters. How can you enter in a script just the regex. You can't separate the two you can only deal with the presentation on the screen. Even then it is just odd characters

Comment: A simpler way to print just the IP addresses is `awk -F' : ' '/nameserver/ {print $2}'`

Comment: What i like about the original suggestion is that it removes duplicates (via `sort -u`). So here is my favorite: `scutil --dns | awk -F: '/nameserver/ {print $2}' | sort -u`

Comment: @shawkinaw I guess this will break with ipv6 right? They are separated by colons... but that's not something anyone would care for the next century probably 

Comment: @estani That's why you need the spaces in the field separator as I put in my comment (`awk -F ' : '` vs. `awk -F:`), then it still works fine with IPv6.

Comment: @shawkinaw I misread the quotes and saw dvo answer, which is omitting them. Very nice!